# Vuejs 3 alternative select binding

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to get a select element bound to a value for a custom object. The crux here is that the object property in question has a custom getter. The value is set as a number, but when accessed returns an associated value as a string. Why I do this is a long story.

So I have an object of key-value pairs making some options:

```
<select v-model="myObject.myProperty">
    <option v-for="v, k in myOptions" :key="k" :value="k">{{v}}</option>
</select>
{{myObject.myProperty}} //this line prints out the correct value
```

But the options are not showing as selected. The value is updated for `myObject.myProperty` and it returns what I expect. I suspect that behind the scenes, it's correctly assigning `k` to my custom object, but that because it returns a different string value, Vue can't inherently figure out which option to mark 'selected'.

Manually adding `:selected` does not help:

```
<option v-for="v, k in myOptions" :key="k" :value="k" :selected="v === myObject.myProperty">{{v}}</option>
```

I also tried to manually bind the select instead of using the v-model attribute, also no:

```
<select :value="myObject.myProperty" @input="myObject.myProperty = $event.target.value"
```

Is there an alternative way to wire up a select/option situation? If not, building a custom component with faux-select functionality is my next step.

---

For clarity, myOptions is a key-value like this

```
{ 
    0 : 'Option 1', 
    1 : 'Option 2',
}
```

But myObject has special setters that take and remember the key, then also a special getter than returns the value from myOptions.

So then:

```
myObject.myProperty = 0;
console.log(myObject.myProperty) //logs 'Option 1'
```

When when I set the value to the key (`k`) I get back the corresponding value when the option is selected and the value of 'myObject.myProperty' is what I expect. Example: I pick 'Option 1' from the drop-down, which has a value of `0` derived from the key `k`.

However, although `myObject.myProperty` has the value I want, I can't get Vue to display the the actual html option as selected, probably because the value returned by `myObject.myProperty` is `'Option 1'` and not `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, the actual answer:

```
<select @input="myObject.myProperty = $event.target.value">
    <option v-for="v, k in myOptions" :selected="myObject.myProperty === v" :key="k" :value="k">{{v}}</option>
</select>
```

`v-model` won't work here because it simply doesn't care that you've manually applied `selected`: it will always try to match the option value to the the `v-model` property value. As this object takes one value with a setter and returns another with a getter, these will never align.

Instead, manually assign the value to the object with `@input` and match the value from the getter to the value in the options for `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question properly or not. Hence, adding my input on your requirement below.

As `myObject.myProperty` returning the value you passed in the `select` and as per your code you are passing the `index` as value.

Hence, while comparing in `:selected` both LHS and RHS should contain `index` of the item you passed.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      myOptions: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'alpha'
      }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'beta'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'gama'
      }],
      myObject: {
        myProperty: ''
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <select v-model="myObject.myProperty">
      <option v-for="(item, index) in myOptions" :selected="myObject.myProperty === item.id" :key="item.id" :value="item.id">{{item.name}}</option>
    </select>
    {{myObject.myProperty}}
  </div>
```

Comment: You get the points because you got me on the right path

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Based on the newly provided information.

In Template:

```
    <select v-model="selectedOption">
      <option v-for="(v, k) in options" :key="k" :value="k">
        {{ v }}
      </option>
    </select>
```

In JS

```
data() {
  return {
    selectedOption: null,
    options: {
      0: 'Option 1',
      1: 'Option 2',
    },
  };
}
```

By setting `selectedOption` with the key of options will correctly display the selected option.

Here is a link to a working example using your data structure. It contains two selects both using the same object for its data source. One with a default selection. the other without.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-efekym?file=src/App.vue

THIS IS NOW OUTDATED BASED ON THE LATEST INFO
<s>Based on the logic in your further examples I think the problem is within conflating your `k` & `v` variables in your loop. Although it is hard to tell because there isn't any sample data or a complete isolated component outlying the behavior.</s>

<s>However in your later examples you have:</s>

<s>`<option v-for="v, k in myOptions" :key="k" :value="k" :selected="v === myObject.myProperty">{{v}}</option>`</s>

<s>I am inferring that you believe that `myObject.myProperty` is holding the value from variable `v`, when in fact you are setting the value as variable `k` as witnessed in `:value="k"`</s>

<s>By correcting this I believe your issue will be resolved, you also noted a int to string conversion. depending on how/where this is happening this could also contribute to your headaches because this will never equate to true. `'1231'` === 1231</s>